# What is the correct way to import this class?

Tags: python, import, module, package

I have the following repository structure:

```
directoryA
    - moduleA.py (it contains MyClass class)
directoryB
    - moduleB.py
```

In moduleB.py I need to import MyClass, I use the following command:

```py
from directoryA.moduleA import MyClass
```

When I run the main() function in moduleB.py I have the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'directoryA'

I run the moduleB.py from directoryB in the following way:

```
py moduleB.py
```

How could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do to organizing your scripts would be using a file called `main.py` in the main folder, which must be in the same directory as `directoryA` and `directoryB`.

In `main.py`, just import the files from child directories:

```py
from directoryA.moduleA import MyClass
import directoryB.moduleB

# Do whatever you want, but sometimes, just don't go too overboard.
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is moduleB.py searches for directoryA inside directoryB, which is the working directory. You can try using two dots to go up one hierarchy level:

```py
from ..directoryA.moduleA import MyClass
```

or you can also try to append the path of the file for the import statement

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work for me